# Azure AD - Only few APIs available in app

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, azure, azure-ad, azure-ad-graph-api

We are creating an App in Azure AD for our product. The app will be multi tenant app which customers can grant access to.

We try to create App in portal.azure.com, in our dev environment we created the app and we were given all All the required APIs to select (We wanted to select ***SharePoint Online***) as shown in below diagram;

[image]

However on new azure AD tenant which we got from local partner, we see only handful of APIs to select from as shown below;

[image]

The difference between both tenancy is, the one which has more APIs (first screenshot) has a valid office 365 subscription while the second screenshot does not have the valid office 365 subscription associated. But we do not want Office 365 subscription for ourselves.

If I just put the required API IDs in manifest, in that case when customer grant our app to their tenancy they receive error something like this;

?error=access_denied&error_description=AADSTS65005%3a+Application+%27%27+is+requesting+permissions+that+are+either+invalid+or+out+of+date.%0d%0aTrace+ID%3a+042bd0a5-f8b4-4fb0-8082-60393df74800%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%3a+a8ffccac-3307-4772-8565-23e5e25e5903%0d%0aTimestamp%3a+2018-07-12+12%3a19%3a54Z

Do we need to purchase office 365 in same tenancy to make its API available to select? That doesnt sounds fair!

Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

As per your description,

You don't have active **Office 365 Subscription** which implies that you will not have SharePoint Online sites.

So if you don't have SharePoint Online sites available what sites to be accessed with **Office 365 SharePoint Online API**.

So You will have to purchase **Office 365 Subscription** to access these APIs.

Comment: As I said ("The app will be multi tenant app which customers can grant access to") this is a multi tenant app. If its a multi-tenant app its not necessary app owner tenant should have all the subscriptions they want their customers to grant for them.